Failed to import MongoDB libraries
I am a beginner java developer. I am currently working on a student management system project. Since I am using VS code I have created my java project using 'no build tool' (Didn't chose Maven Project). I have completed the basics of java alraedy. This is the first time I am working with databases. I chose MongoDB for my project. I am using VS code IDE and I have successfully connected MongoDB to VS code.But whenever I try to import mongodb libraries to my main java code I am encountiring errors.
My main code is working properly. I have tested my main code on Eclipse IDE but in VS code I am facing errors while importing the MongoDB libraries. Since my main code is large and I am facing errors only while importing MongoDB library I am giving a sample code and the error I am facing.
Sample Code:
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

public class MongoDBTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}


My VS code terminal is showing the following error for the bove code:
PS E:\VS Workspace> cd "e:\VS Workspace\Java Project\OneDIU\src" ; if ($?) { javac MongoDBTest.java } ; if ($?) { java MongoDBTest }
MongoDBTest.java:1: error: package com.mongodb.client does not exist
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
^
MongoDBTest.java:2: error: package com.mongodb.client does not exist
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
^
MongoDBTest.java:3: error: package com.mongodb.client does not exist
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
^
MongoDBTest.java:4: error: package com.mongodb.client does not exist
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
^
MongoDBTest.java:5: error: package org.bson does not exist
import org.bson.Document;
^
MongoDBTest.java:6: error: package com.mongodb.client.model does not exist
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
^
MongoDBTest.java:6: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
^
7 errors
PS E:\VS Workspace\Java Project\OneDIU\src>
I tried to search on youtube for solution but no help. I also tried to find similar problem on stackoverflow but failed. Any explaination why I am facing this error and how to solve it is highly appreciated. Thanks!

You need to add the jar files to the classpath. This can be done via -cp mongo-java-driver-#.jar,mongodb-driver-#.jar,mongodb-driver-core-#.jar or via CLASS_PATH environment.

I downloaded the jar file and added it to the reference library in vs code. The previously red marks that were showing are now gone. But whenever I try to run the code the problem persists. The JAR file that I have downloaded is mongo-java-driver-3.12.14.
